# unable to connect with internet in android emulator behind proxy in windows

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am very new to android. I tried to connect to internet behind proxy in windows.But I cant.
I tried with the "-http-proxy" in command line and in eclipse but both did not worked 
for me :( Please suggest me a right way to enable proxy in emulator

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, after setting HTTP_PROXY environment variable and creating a new Emulator in ADV, it was resolved.
Env Variable example:
`HTTP_PROXY=http://your-web-proxy:8080`

Answer (score 1):

Are your proxy settings applied system-wide?
for Windows XP:
`proxycfg -u`
for Vista or 7:
`netsh winhttp set proxy proxy-server="yourproxy.com:3128"`
If yes, check the debug info in command prompt adding the `-debug-proxy` key after `-http-proxy` parameters